# How to open database folder with .ibd file extension in it in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql

I deleted the mysql server and then I lost all the connection in my mysql workbench.
And I figured out how to get the database of those connection.

Finally, I got in the directory, `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\{databasename}`.
Now inorder to restore the database I could see different ways but I cannot find how to open this database in which folder there are all the tables but with `.ibd` extension.
I need help how to open this db folder in my mysql workbench.
Here is the screenshot of the files.
[image]

UPDATE:
After deleting the mysql server 8.0 I downloaded the mysql server 8.1 and now I could see databases in 2 other directories.

Comment: restore the entire data directory exactly the way you found it.

Comment: Please let me know how to restore.
ANy link, or anything. will be very helpful